How to set the same size to all points in PCA from fviz_pca_biplot?
everyone.
I'm working on a PCA using fviz_pca_biplot (factoextra package), but for some reason the points inside it don't have all the same size.
Is there any workaround to solve it?
My code
fviz_pca_biplot(pca_var, col.ind= cafe$Genótipo, 
            label= "var", col.var = "black", legend.title= "Genótipo",
            palette = c("black", "darkgreen", "yellow", "tomato4", 
                        "grey19", "darkviolet", "green3", "lemonchiffon4",
                        "navajowhite", "mediumblue"), 
            pointsize= 3, point= 16, labelsize= 4)



You might want to either hide the centroids (mean points) of the clusters by adding mean.point = FALSE, or set their size with mean.point.size. See documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggpubr/versions/0.6.0/topics/ggscatter

Try adding the argument invisible = "quali" .  Note that posts to SO should be reproducible including all inputs, library statements and code so that others can reproduce it.
